# Recursive dissocPath

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I've just started playing around with Ramda.

I have an initialState, I receive an action prompting me to remove a nested key in the object. This should recursively remove keys one level up if they are the only key at that level.

```
const initialState = {'a': {'x': {}, 'b':{'c': {'d': {}}}}}

const actionPath = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const actionObj = {'a': {'b':{'c': {'d': {}}}}}

//required output {'a': {'x': {}}}
```

I tried doing this with Ramda functions only, but continually blew the stack. I'm at a loss as to how to do this functionally.

Start by deleting the object at the actionPath

```
const newState = R.dissocPath(actionPath, initialState) //{'a': {'x': {}, 'b':{'c':{}}}}}
```

Then move up the actionPath

```
const newPath = R.init(actionPath) //const actionPath = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Check if the next key up is empty

```
R.isEmpty(R.equals(R.path(newPath, newState), {}))
```

If that's true dissoc again and repeat until not empty.
From this point your state would change to:

```
{'a': {'x': {}, 'b':{}}}}
{'a': {'x': {}}}}
```

Then at the last step when you check:

```
R.isEmpty(R.path(['a'], newState))
```

It should return false.

I'm just unsure how to turn this into a function

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  Why do you want to keep x, but not keep b ?

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that:

1. calls `dissoc` on the full path
2. Slices the path up to the last item
3. Calls itself recursively as long as there are items left

Might look something like:

```
const initialState = {'a': {'x': {}, 'b':{'c': {'d': {}}}}}
const actionPath = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

const emptyPath = (aPath, obj) => {
  if (isEmpty(path(aPath, obj), obj)) {
    obj = dissocPath(aPath, obj)
  };

  return aPath.length > 1
    ? emptyPath(aPath.slice(0, -1), obj)
    : obj;
};

emptyPath(actionPath, initialState);
```

You'd probably want to clean up some stuff (handle edge cases like empty paths), curry it, etc. I'm also not sure if there's any other handy Ramda utility that can help you out, since I don't know the library that well.

You can try this code out [here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20initialState%20%3D%20%7B%27a%27%3A%20%7B%27x%27%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%27b%27%3A%7B%27c%27%3A%20%7B%27d%27%3A%20%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%0Aconst%20actionPath%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%2C%20%22d%22%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20emptyPath%20%3D%20%28aPath%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20%28isEmpty%28path%28aPath%2C%20obj%29%2C%20obj%29%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%20dissocPath%28aPath%2C%20obj%29%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20return%20aPath.length%20%3E%201%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20emptyPath%28aPath.slice%280%2C%20-1%29%2C%20obj%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20obj%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AemptyPath%28actionPath%2C%20initialState%29%3B%0A).